# Apply class conditionally angular

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

I am trying to apply class conditionally through ng-class but its not working

```
ng-class="{'margin-watch':progress <= '0','margin-continue-watch':progress > '0' }"
```

Comment: What happens if you unquote the digits?

Comment: You're missing the last double quotes, but I guess it is just a typo in your question. Otherwise your code should work just fine, see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14382/)

Comment: whoever have down voted please tell the reason

Comment: What error do you get if below answers do not solve you problem then?

Comment: Guin you were right removing quotes solved the problem but i accepted Yasser answer for better code readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ng-class="{'margin-watch': (progress <= 0), 'margin-continue-watch': (progress > 0) }
```

Comment: Note the angular brackets are added just to make it more readable, would work without it too.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your condition requires you to compare progress to the character '0', you should remove the quotes around the 0. That should fix your expressions!
For readability I suggest you apply the () as Yasser does in his answer, but it should work without aswell.